# STM32F4 Cycle Fluctuations

Tags: cycle, freertos, stm32f4discovery, lwip

I have STM32F4 running with FreeRTOS and LwIP for networking library. I want to know how much cycle that STM32F4 needs, so I use DWT to measure that. When I ping the STM32F4 and it shows me around 3000 cycles, but after 3-5 times pings it shows me around 6000 cycles after that it shows 3000 cycles. It happen repeatedly. Why this condition happens?  I just curious with this.

Regards

Comment: Probably an interrupt going off.

Comment: What do you mean interrupt going off? @RealtimeRik

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are asking because you are using 'cycles' without defining what you mean, or even what you are measuring, and provide no context information at all.  However, if you are using FreeRTOS then you can use [FreeRTOS+Trace](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_Trace/FreeRTOS_Plus_Trace.shtml) to visualise the execution pattern of your application.